Consumption Logic App Has No Version History
I was going to ask this on Stack Overflow, but then saw that it is not a coding issue that I am having here.
Incident: Logic App Has No Version History
I've got a consumption Logic App (LA) at work (for a client) which has no version history despite hundreds of amendments.
I am unable to screenshot this for multiple reasons, but rest assured there is a Versions screen, that has nothing on it.
Research
I've searched here (one example of that) and must just be bad at it, because I couldn't find a similar issue or question.
I've tried to find a way through the Microsoft troubleshooting, but that just deadends with no endpoints to cover this.
Plus I've not found a suitable Startpage search for this online.
More Info / Next Steps / etc
More Info

Versions Status - As far as I'm aware it has never a Version history, all the other LAs have it, though
Browser - Tried in Firefox, Edge, Brave, FF Nightly, plus in Private Browsing sessions on all
Properties - I've looked all around the LA config and options that I can think of and just haven't found a switch or data toggle to indicate this

Next Steps
If there's a way to enable the version history then that's great, I'll try to get someone with the right permissions to issue the API call.
But my Startpage searches haven't found one.
Is there a way to enable the version history on a specific LA?
